# Filter one specific attribute values from products in magento

Tags: magento

I'm new in magento, I'm working on http://www.theartworkgallery24.com/stage/ website. Please check beneath flash banner, there are 4 big images that are links to attributes value from which user can directly go to a product.

I need a page that display on one specific attribute values like in case of artist, it should be Gustav Klimt, Leonardo Da Vinci etc. These should be links to actual product related to the attribute values.

Please tell me how to make your own PHTML or PHP file, which code to use and how, and in last how to call your code in your magento website.

Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: As I see, all 4 banners already linked to pages which do what you described here. So, have you managed to do it by yourself?

Comment: Zyava, what I've done its not programming, I've made simple pages, in which I've placed attribute values as links to products, but the links are generated by simple search query link, meaning I've personally searched my website through magento and copy the link and placed in my attribute values. I'm not getting attribute values automatically, all is manual and again the links to their products is search query of magento not by any oprogramming.

Comment: In artist page there are two links one is of Gustav Klimt and other is leonardo Da Vinchi, these are attribute values of products, I've personally searched them in magento using magento searching and I've copied the link as http://www.theartworkgallery24.com/stage/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=Gustav, you can change gustav in search query to vinchi for seeing Leonardo Da Vinchi products.

Comment: I need every thing to be automatic, first to get attribute values automatically and then linked them to their products automatically. I It should not be done by way I've done. But I'm sure some one has did that but unfortunately I'm unable to get to that.

Answer (score 0):

You please create an attribute (davinchi) in admin side for these functionality. You can create  products attributes from catalog->attributes->menu.After that you can see these attribute value in product creation page.You just assign it to different products

After that you can either  create a module for this. Otherwise just create a phtml file in catalog/product/ folder.

```
  then enter the below custom collection code in it.

  $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
      //filter codition
  $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'davinchi','eq'=>1),
   ));
  This will load products having attribute value davinchi=1.
```

Comment: First of all I want to show the list of attribute values first then link them to their products. 2nd tell me how can I'll call the code from magento

Comment: Do you want to display products attributes name and total number of products count under each attributes .     That is blue(299)